# Changes in the editor are not saved to file in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

I am using Eclipse Luna- The PHP version and when I make changes in the editor, they are saved in the IDE but not on file. The file on disk remains unchanged. I have tried restarting Eclipse and cleaning the project without success. What could be the problem here?

Comment: What do you mean, "saved in the IDE"? Does the 'dirty' marker go away? Does the file remain saved when you exit and restart Eclipse? Maybe you just accidentally checked the "copy project into workspace" option and you are now editing a copy of the original project?

Comment: The file is saved in Eclipse and remains saved when I close and restart eclipse but the original file on disk is not affected with the changes. I am not aware of making a change to "copy project into workspace", where do I check this setting?

Comment: Right-click on the file in Eclipse and view it's properties. There you should see the path of the file. Compare that to the file you are viewing "on disk". I'd bet that it's a different file. You probably copied it either when you imported the project, or you drag-and-dropped the file into the project. Here, the default option is to copy the file.

Comment: The properties dailog window has; 
Path: /learning-joomla3/plugins/content/clicktocall/clicktocall.php . 

Location: /opt/lampp/htdocs/learning-joomla3/plugins/content/clicktocall/clicktocall.php .

The location corresponds with what I have on disk and I am thinking the Path is relative to the projects in Eclipse. Am I right? I initially created a blank project and imported the files afterwards. When you mention that the default option is to copy the file, how do I change that?